# Cannot receive XML response with angular 8 injected http class

Tags: angular, https, http-headers

I want to execute a HTTP service, and  get a response in XML using angular (v8)

I tried to write a service, then use it into my component.
You can find follow my  "angular" code:

```
getConsultationPointSOAP(wsname:string): Observable<any>{

    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.baseUrl +":"+ PORT_NUM + 
      url+wsname+'?wsdl', 
      httpOptions).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}

private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log(err.message);
    return Observable.throw(err.message);
}
```

Then in my "angular" component

```
    ngOnInit() {

this.soapservice.getConsultationPointSOAPWs(this._url).subscribe(

        response => {
            this.soapservice = response.text;
            console.log("OKEY");
        },
        error => {
            console.log("error");
            console.log(error.text);
        }
    );
}
```

when I execute my code, I get a 200 as web service status and get the XML response on my browser(network tab), but I can't get the result in console, It displays: error, and 
Http failure during parsing for "my_URL".

I am trying multiple solutions, and I will be thankful if you know how can I solve this issue, or is there any parse solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution to this problem, I have to add to the header (pay attention header and not the httpHeaders) the type of response I want to get in the end, in my case: responseType:text, to prevent getting the original format(json), here the related code:

```
getConsultationPointSOAPWs(url: string) {
  this.resultat = this.http.get(url, { 
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
      'Authorization': sessionStorage.getItem('token'),
      'Content-Type': 'application/xml' 
    }), 
    responseType: 'text' 
  });
  return this.resultat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to understand your code structire. Please try to change your below code

```
this.soapservice.getConsultationPointSOAPWs(this._url).subscribe(
ngOnInit() {

    response => {
        this.soapservice = response.text;
        console.log("OKEY");
    },
    error => {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(error.text);
    }
);
}
```

to

```
ngOnInit() {
this.soapservice.getConsultationPointSOAPWs(this._url).subscribe(
response => {
    this.soapservice = response.text;
    console.log("OKEY");
},
error => {
    console.log("error");
    console.log(error.text);
}
);
}
```

Try to change the httpOptions to responseType: text
getConsultationPointSOAP(wsname:string): Observable{

```
return this.http.get<any[]>(this.baseUrl +":"+ PORT_NUM + 
  url+wsname+'?wsdl', 
  {responseType: 'text'}).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
```

}
I hope this will workout. If still it does not work then Make sure that in your backend script you don't define header as -("Content-Type: application/json);

Comment: If the solution worked for you please accept the answer. by clicking right button at right of the my answer.

Comment: It was an error here when writing my question, in my IDE, it was fine.

Comment: Still need an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
ngOnInit() {

this.soapservice.getConsultationPointSOAPWs(this._url,{ responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(

        response => {
            this.soapservice = response;
            console.log("OKEY");
        },
        error => {
            console.log("error");
            console.log(error.text);
        }
    );
}
```

Httpclient get method have second parameter as  option where you can configure headers.
In this scenario we need responsetype as text.Because default respose type is json that could be problem that you were not getting proper xml type response.